# Facebook Ad CTA "Use app" gets stuck in CustomTabActivity

Tags: android, facebook, ads, facebook-android-sdk

There is a problem related to the Facebook Ad campaigns and Facebook Android SDK.
When using the engagement campaign on Facebook with "Use app" CTA, the default behaviour should be to open the app if the user have installed it. 
If I include the CustomTabActivity into the app manifest (as provided in the Facebook SDK Android Login documentation), the CTA button gets stuck in CustomTabActivity, shows blank screen and the app is not opened.
If I remove the CustomTabActivity from the manifest, the app opens normally.

Any idea on this how can I keep the CustomTabActivity and make the CTA button work normally?

Comment: We are facing the same issue... Did u fix it?

Comment: Unfortunatelly no, I just removed the CustomTabActivity from the Manifest. Now the FB login opens the WebView popup to sign up with credentials, but at least the app is not stuck when opened from FB ad.

Comment: @Tomislav We got the same problem now. removing the CustomTabActivity resolves the issue. But is there any other solution?

Comment: It's been a while, but has anyone found a solution?